# Facebook Registration Plugin not redirecting/sending data of logged in users

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe

I have just tried to use the Facebook registration plugin inside an iframe page tab.

In case anyone is wondering why I would want to do this, I want to use the Facebook registration plugin to create a newsletter signup form on my FB page.

I tried with this code:

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration.php?
             client_id=113869198637480&
             redirect_uri=&
             fields=name,birthday,gender,location,email"
        scrolling="auto"
        frameborder="no"
        style="border:none"
        allowTransparency="true"
        width="100%"
        height="330">
</iframe>
```

and this code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId={YOUR_APP_ID}&xfbml=1"></script>

<fb:registration 
  fields="name,birthday,gender,location,email" 
  redirect-uri=""
  width="530">
</fb:registration>
```

In both cases I used the APP_ID of the page tab application, and the canvas url for that page tab, but I filled out the website field with the website being used.

WHen I take out the pre-filled FB info and fill out the form, a var_dump on the receiving page gives out the right info, but when I submit it with the pre-filled FB info, it does a popup saying, you are registering with APP_NAME_HERE, if you want to do this click continue, or undo if you don't (something like that) and when I click continue nothing happens.

I have used Firebug to inspect the page, and I think that the data is being sent to another iframe, but I don't know how to access it. I have tried changing target to _top, _self and _parent but this didn't work either. I also tried creating a new app specifically using the website attribute, and that failed in the same way too. ANy help gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the `target` attribute is broken when using pre-filled info. Perhaps it has something to do with the way the flow must happen when the confirmation popup appears, but AFAIK it's not documented that the two cannot be used together. In any case, the pre-filled data seems to have the effect of forcing `target=_top` no matter what you specify in the attributes.

That being the case, you will have to specify an external page address as the `redirect_uri` and process the data there and then redirect back to the Facebook page address. If necessary you can pass some data back using the app_data parameter in the query string.

Comment: You misunderstand, the redirect_uri is left blank in the example because it is generated by php. I am using an external url in the live example, which works in IE and Chrome, but not FF. The test area is here: http://www.facebook.com/smallcoders?sk=app_257443180968911. If you hit the register button in Chrome, or IE (9) then you can see that it redirects to a page showing the count of fields in the signed_request['registration'] array, and listing the keys. But in FF nothing happens.

Comment: That's clearly a very different scenario than stated in your original question. Are you saying that in FF, when you click Continue in the popup, that the popup just disappears and no redirect happens? It seems to work properly for me using FF 3.6, I get redirected to a page that says "The Signed Request Registration field has 4 Fields, they are as follows: name, email, location, gender". And it always worked for me in tests with my own tab. So it looks like it may be something with your browser in particular.

Comment: I also tried it in FF7, and again it seems to work properly. I do see a warning about insecure content, so possibly that could be to blame if there were an option set somewhere to not load such pages (I didn't see any such option in the FF setup, but still worth checking). If you haven't already, you should test it from another computer since it seems likely to be something in your particular browser settings.

Answer (score 0):

Most than likely you are already flagged as registered and are receiving back the cookie/header for FB connect to work. If this is the case you will need to un-register your application on facebook in the application management page. Once you do that the button will work again.

> Lastly, if the user is logged into Facebook and already connected to
>   your application, the button will say Login and won't do anything when
>   clicked (but your application should detect this state using the
>   getLoginStatus method and not show the button).

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/

You can debug your registration status using

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
    if(!response.authResponse) return;
    console.log(response)
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Looks to me that you are missing something:

[< fb:register >](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/advanced/)

Here you can see that tha attribute onvalidate, which contains the name of the js function called after the Register button is pressed, to whom is passed the whole object containing the user info.
Greetings ;)
Luca

Comment: That just let's them register for facebook.

Answer (score -1):

In the second code redirect-uri="" needs a value. It needs to be prefixed by your site url.

Comment: Assuming the OP didn't deliberately leave that blank, that could definitely be the problem

Comment: I did leave it blank just for the asking